# What is the correct way to refer to this function using c++?

Tags: c++, xcode, class

I'm writing a program that's meant to eventually work as a yatzy game for a course I'm doing in c++ programming. I have been given a class called Die from the course that I'm meant to use and I'm not allowed to change it. When trying to refer to a specific function within the class given to me Xcode issues a warning saying "Cannot refer to type member 'Die' in 'Die' with '.'. This is the code I'm having problems with:

```
 for (i = 100; i > 0; i--)  
{
    Die D;
    D.Die(); //This is the line not working
    D.rollDie(); 
    dice_value = D.getDieValue();
```

Is there any other way to refer to a function? Does anybody know what could be causing this problem? I really appreciate any help given!

Comment: I don't remember much C++, but don't you need a Die D = new Die()?

Comment: That's a Java-ism, not a C++ism. the `new` keyword in Java works very differently from C++.

Comment: Just so you understand the message: `D.Die` refers to the class `Die`. Any class has its class name as a member refer to itself for certain reasons, in C++. So you can do `Die::Die::Die::Die::...::Die::staticMemberFunction()` for example.

Comment: @Dave: No, that's Java or C#. In C++, `Die D` refers to a stack object, which doesn't require heap allocation via `new`.

Comment: @Dave: No. @Jonathan Grynspan: `new` in both languages does not differ that much, the main difference is in the languages themselves, where Java is a *reference* language (user defined types are reference types) and C++ is a *value* language (user defined have value semantics), even if you can create pointers and use reference semantics.

Comment: Ok, I remember that now that you've reminded me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you to everybody who answered! I deleted that line and now everything works as it should :D

Comment: @elinfrisk you can give up votes to the answers that you found useful, and also select the most useful one. That will make it more likely that people will give good answers to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need that line of code at all. D's default constructor is called automatically by the compiler for any object instantiated on the stack (i.e., local variables).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call `Die`'s constructor, don't: you've already done that.

```
Die D;
```

calls `Die`'s default constructor already. `D` is initialized after that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
Die D;
D.Die(); //This is the line not working
```

Thats not good. Die D allready calls a constructor !